# How to select a random element in std::set?

Tags: c++, iterator, set

How can I select a random element in an `std::set`?

I naively tried this:

```
int GetSample(const std::set<int>& s) {
  double r = rand() % s.size();
  return *(s.begin() + r); // compile error
}
```

But the `operator+` is not allowed in this way.

Comment: Be carefull of using modulus (%) in random number generation the distribution may not be exactly even (last element is less likely than the others).

Comment: [Modulo bias is something you should consider when s.size() is large compared with `RAND_MAX`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16006723/111307)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could use the `std::advance` method.

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  // generate a set...
  set<int> s;
  for( int i = 0; i != 10; ++i ) s.insert(i);
  auto r = rand() % s.size(); // not _really_ random
  auto n = *select_random(s, r);
}
```

Where

```
template<typename S>
auto select_random(const S &s, size_t n) {
  auto it = std::begin(s);
  // 'advance' the iterator n times
  std::advance(it,n);
  return it;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that method. Thanks, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Any solution will be O(N). Proof is left as an exercise, hint: how many elements of a std::set can be reached in constant time?

Comment: Could be O(logN). std::set is stored in some kind of tree, there could potentially be a solution that just goes down on one of the branches, and is done.

Comment: The method in my answer using a sorted vector is O(1).

Comment: @davidhigh True, but in that case insertion and removal are O(N). That seems like cheating, but it depends on the use-case, of course. When you fill the vector once, that's fine.

Comment: @Jonas: sure, but the question here was only about random selection ... so I didn't care about the others :-)

Comment: @Kiscsirke You're right that with balanced search trees you can have O(log(N)) for insertion, removal, and random access. However, the latter requires that nodes store how many children they have to either their left or right. This needs to be updated during insertion, removal, and rebalancing. Since `std::set` and `std::map` hide the tree-internals from the user, they cannot be used to achieve this. I ended up implementing my own search tree. It's definitely possible to get O(log(N)) lookup.

Comment: this answer would be much better if it answered the question "how can I *select* a *random* element from a set", currently as far as I can tell it shows neither randomness nor element selection, though it gives you the tools to piece it together

Comment: @Timofey that's right.  The 'problem' OP had was not the question he asked :).  Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @xtofl it was a good answer, but it's that much better if the whole solution is given! really appreciate it, thank you

Answer (score 3):

**C++17 `std::sample`**

This will be a convenient, although not very efficient (O(n)) method:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::set<int> in{1, 2, 3, 5, 7};
    std::vector<int> out;
    std::sample(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out),
                3, std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
    for (auto i : out)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

But I think that for efficiency you just need to copy to another type of structure: [How to select a random element in std::set in less than O(n) time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302231/how-to-select-a-random-element-in-stdset-in-less-than-on-time?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

If the random access is important and you can live with O(N) average effort for the insertion, then the workaround given in [this paper](http://www.lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf) might be convenient.

The main idea there is to use a sorted vector, and then for lookup the function `std::lower_bound`. This, the lookup takes O(log N) just as in a normal set. Further, (random) insertion takes O(N), as all following elements must be shifted just like in a normal vector (and possibly a reallocation is performed). Insertion at the back, however, is constant (except for the reallocation. You can avoid this by calling `reserve()` with a large enough storage).

**Finally, the main point of the question: Random access is O(1).** Just draw a random number `i` from a uniform distribution in `[0, V.size()-1]`, and return the corresponding element `V[i]`.

Here is the code basis out of the paper, which implements this sorted vector. Extend it as needed:

```
template <class T, class Compare = std::less<T> >
struct sorted_vector {
 using std::vector;
 using std::lower_bound;
 vector<T> V;
 Compare cmp; 
 typedef typename vector<T>::iterator iterator;
 typedef typename vector<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;
 iterator begin() { return V.begin(); }
 iterator end() { return V.end(); }
 const_iterator begin() const { return V.begin(); }
 const_iterator end() const { return V.end(); }

 //...if needed, implement more by yourself

 sorted_vector(const Compare& c = Compare()) : V(), cmp(c) {}
 template <class InputIterator>
 sorted_vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Const Compare& c = Compare())
 : V(first, last), cmp(c)
 {
 std::sort(begin(), end(), cmp);
 }

 //...

 iterator insert(const T& t) {
     iterator i = lower_bound(begin(), end(), t, cmp);
     if (i == end() || cmp(t, *i))
        V.insert(i, t);
      return i;
 }
 const_iterator find(const T& t) const {
     const_iterator i = lower_bound(begin(), end(), t, cmp);
      return i == end() || cmp(t, *i) ? end() : i;
 }
};
```

For a more sophisticated implementation, you might also consider [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3217/An-STL-compliant-sorted-vector).

EDIT: or even better, use `boost::container::flat_set`, which implements the set using the idea above, i.e. as a sorted vector.

Comment: If you know the `set` is not going to change after you start taking random samples, or it changes very infrequently, you could also cache it in a `vector` when it changes and just pick from there. You could wrap that cached `set` up any way you please to make it transparent (writes invalidate cache, cache rebuilt if invalid on read).

Answer (score 2):

## First Solution : *O(log n)* in time / *O(1)* in space (not uniform !)

A hypothesized in a comment above, it can be done in *O(log(n))* (vs *O(n)* for `std::advance`) without a vector (using *O(n)* more space) by using the method I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31522686/2312686).

Essentially, you :

- check if the set is empty (if it is, there is no hope)
- generate a random value
- if already there return it else insert it
- get one iterator `it` on it
- get the random element as `*(it++)` or `*(set.begin())` if `it` at the end
- return it not before deleting the element you inserted

n.b : As pointed out by *Aaron* the element is not chosen *uniformly* at random. You need to build the random element with the same distribution than the elements in the set to approach a uniform polling.

## Second Solution : *O(1)* in time / *O(n)* in space (uniform)

*davidhigh* already gave the solution with a vector but there is a problem because when you *pop* an element of your stack, you will have to perform a linear search in *O(n)* or you can rebuild your vector each time you want to retrieve a random element but that is *O(n)* too.

To avoid this problem and keep the insert/delete to *O(log n)*, you can keep an `std::unordered_set` and use a [similar method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31522686/2312686) to the first solution to get a random element in *O(1)*.

p.s : If your elements are large you can use an unordered set of pointers (with a modified hasher) to spare some memory.

Comment: That is random yes, but it is not *uniformly* at random from the current elements of the set. And we can assume the questioner wants uniformity. Although maybe this is not entirely necessary

Comment: Indeed though if you generate your element with a distribution that look like the set that would approach it.  We don't have this issue with the unordered_set (see the link in the answer). Need to think about it...

Answer (score 2):

To get a random element from a set first take a random number using rand() function then take a modulas (%) by set size so that our iterator will not go out of bounds. Now, to get random element just iterate idx=rand() % s.size() times to get random element. In this method each element has same probability of occurring.

```cpp
// making set
unordered_set<int> s;
s.insert(1);
s.insert(2);
s.insert(3);
s.insert(4);

// logic
int idx = rand()%s.size();
auto it = s.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < idx; i++)
{
    it++;
}
return *it;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int GetSample(const std::set<int>& s) {
  double r = rand() % s.size();
  std::set<int>::iterator it = s.begin();
  for (; r != 0; r--) it++;
  return *it;
}
```

would be one way of doing it, although not pretty;

Comment: This code is incorrect, you cannot simply check double for equality. And why double here?

Answer (score 0):

```
 **You can simply pass random parameter as second parameter to get random iterator and 
 after that you can easily get element corresponding to it**
 #include <iostream>
 #include <unordered_set>
 #include <cstdlib>

 int main() {
 std::unordered_set<int> mySet;

 //Insert 10 elements into the set
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
    mySet.insert(i);
 }

// Display the set
std::cout << "Set elements: ";
for (int element : mySet) {
    std::cout << element << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;

// Get a random element
int randomElement = *(std::next(mySet.begin(), rand() % mySet.size()));

std::cout << "Random Element: " << randomElement << std::endl;


return 0;
}
```