# Any efficient building function in C++/C to fast uniformly sample b entries without replacement from n entries?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

It seems that, using `shuffle(Index, Index+n, g)` before getting the first `b` entries is still not efficient when `n` is very big but `b` is very small, where Index is a vector/array storing `0 ... (n-1)`.

Comment: If you're grabbing fewer than `n` entries, why not sample indices instead of shuffling the entire collection?

Comment: @AndyG Yes, but then how to do?

Comment: @olivia: with [`sample`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/sample) perhaps?

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3052788/1460794).

Answer (score 1):

You can take the [standard shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and modify it to stop after shuffling just the first `b` entries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different idea than what sh1 suggests.
Unlike a previous answer it is mathematically sound. No % BS.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <random>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // Configuration.
    auto constexpr n = 100;
    auto constexpr b = 10;

    // Building blocks for randomness.
    auto const seed = std::mt19937::result_type{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::cout << "seed = " << seed << std::endl;
    auto engine = std::mt19937{ seed };
    auto distribution = std::uniform_int_distribution<>{};

    // Creating the data source. Not part of the solution.
    auto reservoir = std::vector<int>{};
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(reservoir), n, 
        [i = 0]() mutable { return i++; });

    // Creating the sample.
    // Idea attributed to Bob Floyd by Jon Bentley in Programming Pearls 2nd Edition.
    auto sample = std::set<int>{};
    for (auto i = n - b; i != n; ++i)
    {
        auto const param = std::uniform_int_distribution<>::param_type(0, i);
        auto const j = distribution(engine, param);
        (sample.find(j) == sample.cend()) 
            ? sample.insert(j) 
            : sample.insert(i);
    }

    // Converting the sample to an output vector and shuffle it, if necessary.
    auto output = std::vector<int>(std::cbegin(sample), std::cend(sample));
    std::shuffle(std::begin(output), std::end(output), engine);

    // Print out the result.
    for (auto const x : output) { std::cout << x << " "; }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```